# rails rack cache - how to manually clear all the cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-cache

I cached a page via rack-cache, and now the browser never displays the updated page cuz its showing the cached version.

how do I clear all the cache?  (Note: I deleted all the cached pages from the rails_app_root/public directory).  I even tried disabling rack-cache but it still shows the cached version of the page.

any ideas?

Comment: tried it, didn't help.  I've also tried Rails.cache.clear, still doesn't work.  I've completely removed all Rack::Cache code and caches_page code, but still its showing the old page..i''m really confused

Comment: also, in my routes, map.root is mapped to /public/home, if I go to http://localhost:3000 it still shows some old cached page, but if I access http://localhost:3000/public/home it shows a fresh page, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

in terminal:

```
rake tmp:cache:clear
```

or in rails console:

```
Rails.cache.clear
```